# CloudKit UserRecordID - Callback with no User Identity

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I am trying to get the CloudKit User's first and last name.

Here is the code:

```
container.fetchUserRecordID { (recordID, error) in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let recordID = recordID else { return }

        self.container.discoverUserInfo(withUserRecordID: recordID) { (info, fetchError) in
            // use info.firstName and info.lastName however you need
            print(info?.displayContact?.givenName)
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following message **when running the print line**: [LogFacilityCK] Got a user discovery progress callback with no user identity: {
    FetchInfo = ">";
}

The info variable is showing as nil when debugging.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If `info` is `nil`, then log `fetchError`.

Comment: Both 'info' and 'fetchError' are 'nil'

Comment: @rmaddy any thoughts on why both are nil?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got the users' name:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
        CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
            CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
                userName = (userID?.nameComponents?.givenName)! + " " + (userID?.nameComponents?.familyName)!
                print("CK User Name: " + userName)
            })
        }
    }
```